# why can't I download apps with 29 gigabytes of free memory on sd card

Tags: insufficient-memory

I have 29 gigabytes of free storage on my sd card yet when I try to download more apps I get the insufficient storage message. All apps that I am able to move to sd card are. No matter how many apps I download the amount of free storage on sd card remains at 29 gigabytes.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! You've already found the correct tag for your question. What you might have missed is our tags have wikis. May I suggest you check with the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) to understand what's behind your issue, and check if some of our collected first-aid helps you? Main point: for this error it's completely irrelevant how much space you've got *on your SD card* – all it cares for is your *internal storage.*

Answer (score 2):

Your android device has internal and in your case external storage.
 The external storage is, in this case, your SD card with 29GB of free memory.
However most of the android apps get installed on your internal storage. You can check if your internal storage is filled up by going into "**Settings -> Storage**" and looking at the internal storage. 
If it is filled up try to move apps to your sd card by going to "**Settings -> Apps -> Manage Apps**" and you will see a list of installed applications.
 Click them one by one and in the menu you'll see an option "Move to SD Card" for some of the applications. 
You can alternatively root your device (or update to android V6.0+) and move all of your apps to your SD card using an app on the Google Play Store called AppMGR III.

Answer (score 0):

All internal memory can not be used for installing apps. I think android allot a part of your internal memory for installation of apps. When that money is full, you start receiving lie memory error message. You can try following:

1. Uninstall some Apps
2. Move apps to external storage or money card. You can do that by going to app settings. You may be able to move some apps by app settings option.
3. If you're still getting low memory issue, then you use [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ljmobile.move.app&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dmove%20to%20sd%20card%20app&pcampaignid=APPU_1_lBMtWM6GMYm4apmwq5AH). This is only app I found on play store which can move those apps to SD card which android app settings couldn't. But to use this, you need to be **rooted**.